# Как узнать номер строки?

Tags: javascript

Надо сделать что-то вроде `console.log()` в хроме, когда рядом отображается номер строки, где вызвался этот метод.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если я правильно вас понял, то попробуйте так (только chrome):

```
console.line = function (offset){
    var halt;
    try { halt(); } catch( error ){
        var info = error.stack.split('\n')[2 + ~~offset].match(/at\s+([^\s]+)\s+\((.+):(\d+):/);
        console.info('"'+info[1]+'": line '+info[3]+' in '+info[2]);
    }
};

console.spy = function (ctx, name){
    var fn = ctx[name];
    ctx[name] = function (){
        console.line(1);
        return fn.apply(ctx, arguments);
    };
};

// название метода, номер строки и имя файла
console.line();

// название и номер строки метода, который вызвал эту функцию
console.spy(document, 'addEventListener');
```

Пример — http://jsfiddle.net/qpqF9/

Answer (score 3):

Думаю самый простой вариант кинуть исключение, а затем разобрать stacktrace:

```
console.getLine = function() {

    function getError()
    {
        try { throw new Error() }
        catch(err) { return err }
    }

    return parseInt(getError().stack.replace(/[\(|\)]/g, '').match(/:(\d+)(:\d+)?[\n]?$/g)[0].substr(1));
}
alert(console.getLine());
```

Демо: http://jsfiddle.net/kLgMC/4/ (работает в Chrome, Opera, Firefox и IE)

Comment: бага http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/kLgMC/5/

Comment: да, действительно вывод идет неверно при вызове в отдельном методе

Answer (score 0):

```js
myLog((new Error).stack); 
function myLog(stack){
// ..parse Stack
// return parse Stack

}
```